# jqGrid Delete Row with ID passed

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**My jqGrid script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var delete_task_url = "/controller/deleteRecordAction";
var gr = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:call_url,
        datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30],
    colNames:['Task#','Project ID','Task Name', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Created By', 'Created Date', 'Status', 'Action'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'USER_ID',index:'TASK_ID', align:'center',search:false },
        {name:'USER_NAME',index:'TASK_NAME', search:false},
        {name:'ACTION',index:'link', search:false,align:'center',sortable:false, formatter: 'actions',
        formatoptions: {
            keys: true,
            editformbutton: true,
            delOptions: { url: delete_task_url}
        }},
    ],
    pager: "#page",
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'TASK_ID',
    caption: "Task List",
    gridComplete: function () {
                    var recs = $("#grid").getGridParam("records");
                    $( ".mycontent" ).remove();
                    if (recs == 0 || recs == null) {
                        $('#grid').after("<div class='mycontent' style='color:red;text-align:center'>No Record Found</div>");

                    }

                }
}).navGrid('#page',{ edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:false,cloneToTop:true,refresh:false},
            {

             },{
             //add options


             },{

                        //msg: "do you really want delete this keyword? This delete affect on Eqms filter"

                });
                jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true  });
            var topPagerDiv = $('#grid_toppager')[0]; 
            jQuery("#grid_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove();

</script>
```

**Demo Followed:**

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbguy5689/9ueDL/6/)

I do not have any checkbox where I can pass `UserId` and based on that selection delete the record. How can I pass `UserId` when clicked on `trash` icon and delete the record ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `USER_ID` column contains unique id data then you can just add `key: true` property to the definition of the column `USER_ID` in `colModel`. As the result jqGrid will post the data in the form `oper=del&id=48803` to the server. If you want to have `oper=del&id=48803` instead you can use `prmNames: { id: "USER_ID" }` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) additionally. As the result the name of parameter, which will be posted to the server, during editing/deleting of the data will be changed to `oper=del&USER_ID=48803`.

By the way the line `var gr = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');` at the beginning of your code should be removed because one try to get the value of `selrow` parameter *before* the grid will be created. I recommend you to add `gridview: true` option to the grid additionally.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I included the link on the [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) word. `prmNames: { id: "USER_ID" }` is the same option of jqGrid like `url`, `datatype`, `height`, `rowNum` and other which you use. `formatter: 'actions'` uses [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) internally to delete the row. It's default option `reloadAfterSubmit` is true. So the grid will be automatically reloaded after deleting of the row. You can use `delOptions` to specify options of `delGridRow`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am stuck on how can I redirect when user clicks on `edit` icon. `editformbutton` is set to true and so it shows a popup instead of redirecting to another page. While on delete it works perfect.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: You are welcome! Redirection of "edit" icon seams to me another question. To help other users to find it one should open new question. You should describe exactly what you want. `editformbutton` have no relation to Delete button. If you use `editformbutton: true` then form editing will be used for Edit operation. Default value is `editformbutton: false` which meant inline editing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I truly appreciate your answers.